# Cannot reshape array of size 47040000 into shape (60000,32,32,1) for pre-trained neural network

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, google-colaboratory, vgg-net

I use the fashionmnist dataset, which contains 60,000 black and white 28x28 images.
The architecture I use is vgg16. But it does not accept the dimensions of the photos and we have to resize them.
Can you help and tell me what code I should use to resize.

[image]

Comment: The values you are reshaping to should equal the size of the original array. 60000*32*32 != 47040000. Whatever you reshape it to should have the same dimensions as the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `reshape` an array into a different number of pixels. What you're looking for is a way to resize. You can use `PIL` for that.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (32, 32, 3)).astype('uint8') # random image
```

```
Out[36]: 
array([[[164, 205,  41],
        [ 29, 187, 195],
        [ 33,  44, 175],
        ...,
        [154,  76, 179],
        [243, 127, 170],
        [ 51, 133, 130]], # etc...
```

```
img = Image.fromarray(img).resize((28, 28), 1) # resize
img = np.array(img) # re-transform into an array
```

Comment: hi,Thank you for your help. But when I use code it gives" invalid syntax"

Comment: That means you made a spelling mistake

Comment: img = Image.fromarray(img).resize((28, 28), 1)) # resize
img = np.array(img) # re-transform into an array


File "<ipython-input-15-05aed353a744>", line 1
    img = Image.fromarray(img).resize((28, 28), 1)) # resize
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thankful, Unfortunately, the code in the program is not working properly. May I ask you to send the code to you and notice its error